# Circe: Generic Function that returns a specific object of a Sealed Trait (ADT)

Tags: scala, generics, circe

I want to do something like this:

```
  def loadYaml[T <: Component](ref: LocalRef): Task[T] = {
    val yamlString = Source.fromResource(ref.url).mkString
    val json: Either[ParsingFailure, Json] = parser.parse(yamlString)
    val component = json.flatMap(_.as[T]) // this line creates the error
    Task.fromEither(component)
  }
```

The decoding throws:

```
Error:(54, 22) could not find implicit value for parameter d: io.circe.Decoder[T]
        .flatMap(_.as[T])
```

`Component` is the Sealed Trait.

Is this not possible with **circe**?

This works (`Component` instead of `T`):

```
  def loadYaml(ref: LocalRef): Task[Component] = {
    val yamlString = Source.fromResource(ref.url).mkString
    val json: Either[ParsingFailure, Json] = parser.parse(yamlString)
    val component = json.flatMap(_.as[Component]) // this line creates the error
    Task.fromEither(component)
  }
```

I don't think the problem is the `Decoder` as it works with `Components`, here it is anyway:

```
  implicit val decodeEvent: Decoder[Component] =
    List[Decoder[Component]](
      Decoder[DbConnection].widen,
      Decoder[DbLookup].widen
    ).reduceLeft(_ or _)
```

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez   I don't think the problem is the Decoder as it works with Components. To be sure I added it to my question.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks, that works! If you have an explanation please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen on the [**documentation**](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/Json.html#as[A](implicitd:io.circe.Decoder[A]):io.circe.Decoder.Result[A]) the `as` method on the **Json** class, requires an `implicit Decoder[T]`.
Since this decoder was not on the scope of the function, the compiler complied about it:

> Error:(54, 22) could not find implicit value for parameter d: io.circe.Decoder[T]
>   .flatMap(_.as[T])

The simplest solution is to just add this implicit to the method and leave the responsibility of providing it to the caller.

```
def loadYaml[T <: Component](ref: LocalRef)(implicit ev: Decoder[T]): Task[T] = ...

// Or even shorter (and clearer IMHO) using a context bound.
loadYaml[T <: Component : Decoder](ref: LocalRef): Task[T] = ...
```